# regex that continues matching numbers until it hits a certain character

Tags: regex

Could someone help me write a regex that starts matching, in a string, any numbers 0 through 9, commas, periods, or parentheses for as long as they go until it hits a space or one of these symbols: +,-,*, or /?

Comment: What if it hits something else, like a letter...?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you would build a regex that only *matches any numbers 0 through 9, commas, periods, or parentheses* multiple times it will automatically not match the spaces or +-*/ after them.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) expression:

```
[\d,.()]+($|(?=[-+*/\s]))
```

Comment: fyi It won't match a simple number `123`, question is not clear whether that is intended or not.

Comment: I've changed it to also match at the end of the string. Don't know if that's wanted or not.

Comment: The lookahead is quite unnecessary, isn't it? Your character class won't match any of these chars anyway.

Comment: I interpret the question as **requiring** that the number be followed by one of those characters. So `123*` matches, but `123a` doesn't.

Comment: So in 'The easter bunny is great ((4+5)*2) and chicken it would great with vegetables.' Only ((4+5)*2) would be extracted. And in the phrase "Donald duck has [5+2]*(4+{5/7}) a silly 2) voice. It only extracts [5+2]*(4+{5/7}). So it starts at any of the following opening-parentheses, opening-brackets, or opening-braces, numbers and continues to match including  continue to match numbers, parethes, braces, brackets, +, -, *, /, and stops at the first space or last closing-parentheses, closing-bracket, or closing-brace.

Answer (score 1):

*Until it hits a space or one of these symbols* typically is `[^ */+-]+`.